# Unable to identify the Limit of Young Generation Space in V8

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, v8

I am researching about --max-semi-space-size in NodeJS and have gone through articles online. However, I found the following text from a 6 years old [blog](https://v8.dev/blog/orinoco-parallel-scavenger#:%7E:text=Since%20the%20young%20generation%20is,young%20generation%20into%20two%20halves.) from v8

> Since the young generation is relatively small (up to 16MiB in V8) it fills up quickly with objects and requires frequent collections. Until M62, V8 used a Cheney semispace copying garbage collector (see below) that divides the young generation into two halves.

Now, as per the NodeJS Documentation:

> Sets the maximum semi-space size for V8's scavenge garbage collector
> in MiB (megabytes). Increasing the max size of a semi-space may
> improve throughput for Node.js at the cost of more memory consumption

Now if we establish that V8's Young Generation can hold upto 16 MB, but then, we know that Young Generation is 3 x Semi-Space Size set [[source]](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cli.html#:%7E:text=Since%20the%20young%20generation), so both statements are contradictory. I am sensing that First Statement about 16MB Limit is old and incorrect in current scenarios, but couldn't find anything. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

(V8 developer here.)

I'm not sure where you are seeing a contradiction.

V8 dynamically adapts the size of the young generation to react to the behavior (in particular: allocation rate and promotion rate) of the application, within certain limits. There's a default maximum, and a command-line flag to override it.

You can set your maximum young generation size to almost anything you want. That's usually not a good idea though: the defaults are chosen very carefully, and offer an overall tradeoff that's usually pretty good. It's quite a rare case that a particular application happens to have such a particular allocation pattern that it gets unlucky with the default rules and benefits from some customization.

The young generation is implemented as *two* semi-spaces; one of them is always empty, so it's fair to use the terms "young generation size" and "semi-space size" interchangeably. The right choice/interpretation of terms depends on the perspective you're interested in though: the size of the memory reservation from the OS that's used for the young generation equals the combined size of both semi-spaces; the maximum size of all objects in the young generation equals the size of one semi-space.

So, for the record and future readers:

> we know that Young Generation is 3 x Semi-Space Size

No, there are two semi-spaces. (It's in the name: "semi" means "half".)
And all objects in the young generation are in one of these semi-spaces.

And there's a very good chance that all of this will be outdated Soon™, when Conservative Stack Scanning forces us to switch to a non-moving young generation collector. There'll probably be a blog post when that happens :-)

> Increasing the max size of a semi-space may improve throughput for Node.js at the cost of more memory consumption

Well, the key word in that sentence would be "*may*". Increasing the max semi-space size may also hurt throughput; there are very good reasons for having a relatively small young generation. Don't just crank up the limit unless you've measured that that's actually beneficial for the workload you care about (because chances are it's not).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It completely makes sense. ...... quick question about the 3x size though... this is what I got from NodeJS Documentation: "Since the young generation size of the V8 heap is three times the size of the semi-space, an increase of 1 MiB to semi-space applies to each of the three individual semi-spaces and causes the heap size to increase by 3 MiB" It was not really clear to me what it meant

Comment: While the confusion has gone away, because the "upto 16MB" statement actually means that it is the default value, which can always be overridden, I would like to thank you for extra explanation you provided there.